How RNN layers see batch data during training?
I want to understand better step by step process how a single-batch data interacts with RNN (or LSTM) layer units for scalar time series.
I understand that RNNs are dense, meaning each unit (neuron) within a layer sees full time sequences somehow, but the full process of training is escaping me. Are time steps fed step by step, or all at once? How does this process interacts with the states from a
prior unit?
